# AngularJS: How to translate a md-placeholder?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-translate

I have a very simple datepicker using AngularJS and I want to give it a placeholder to translate it using AngularJS translate (like I do usually in my project).

#### Here's my HTML code:

```
<div flex class="layout-row">
        <md-datepicker ng-model="vm.calendarEvent.start" ng-model-options="{ timezone: 'UTC' }" md-placeholder="Une date" translate translate-md-placeholder="PROF.SHARE.DUE">
        </md-datepicker>
</div>
```

#### Doing so throws me this error:

> Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [mdDatepicker (module:
>   material.components.datepicker), translate (module:
>   pascalprecht.translate)] asking for new/isolated scope on:
>
> < md-datepicker class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid
>   _md-datepicker-has-triangle-icon" ng-model="vm.calendarEvent.start" ng-model-options="{ timezone: 'UTC' }" md-placeholder="Une date"
>   translate="" translate-md-placeholder="PROF.SHARE.DUE">

Comment: What exactly is `translate-md-placeholder` could you provide a llink to the documentation of this directive?

Comment: idk if it exists... i couldn't find proper angular-translate doc, and i saw a demo code that just did translate-*the property to translate*

Comment: I brought you to 161 orsu enjoy the rep!

Comment: @nicholaslabrecque ahah thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for this inline translation on `md-placeholder`:

```
<div flex class="layout-row">
  <md-datepicker ng-model="vm.calendarEvent.start" 
                 ng-model-options="{ timezone: 'UTC' }" 
                 md-placeholder="{{ 'PROF.SHARE.DUE' | translate  }}">
  </md-datepicker>
</div>
```

Comment: i did the change, now i got >Syntax Error: Token ''PROF.SHARE.DUE'' is not a valid identifier at column 13 of the expression [translate | 'PROF.SHARE.DUE'] starting at ['PROF.SHARE.DUE'].

Comment: @Orsu Check the update please ... it should be `{{ 'PROF.SHARE.DUE' | translate  }}` not `{{ translate   |  'PROF.SHARE.DUE' }}`

Comment: just checked ! works perfectly fine :) thank you (where did you learned this ?)

Comment: @Orsu by reading the documentation https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide ;)

Comment: @Orsu pushed ya ;-) ... SO needs more nice users like you.

Comment: well thank you ^^ (i can't accept as answer just now i have to wait a min or something like this) -- done